# Error installing Vips

Tags: centos6

I am trying to install [Vips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Supported#Unix), I've downloaded the latest files:

wget http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/vips-7.30.0.tar.gz

wget http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/nip2-7.30.1.tar.gz

And on `./configure` I get:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.6 gmodule-2.0 >= 2.4 libxml-2.0 gobject-2.0) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'gmodule-2.0' found
No package 'gobject-2.0' found
```

However I have tried `yum install glib2` and rerun ./configure but get the same error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo yum install glib2-devel` and try again.